# singularity container using package from outside of container

Tags: linux, containers, singularity-container

I created a singularity container with conda just to install the packages faster. However, I noticed that when I use the container if there is already a package installed in my system that is the same as installed in the conda singularity container it will use that one instead of the one in the container and I was wondering if there was a way to stop that from happening.

Example: deepspeed 0.9.5 is the one in the conda environment inside the container but when I do pip show deepspeed the location is the path where my deepspeed 0.9.1 is located and if I run a deepspeed example it will try to use deepspeed 0.9.1 instead of the one in the container

I expected for it to use the one inside the container because I am inside the container

Comment: Did you try running with `--cleanenv` ?